# Extending CDS view fails

Tags: abap, cds

I have two CDS views, ztest_cds and ztex_cds where `ztest_cds` a normal view, and `ztex_cds` is a view that extends `ztest_cds`.

In `ztex_cds`, I associate another table. When I active `ztest_cds`, I receive
this error message:

> Table name _book unknown or shadowed by an alias

when I double click, `ztex_cds` comes to front, and when I click "Activate', it's ends with `NO` error and warning.

**ztest_cds** code:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'zt_cds'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
@EndUserText.label: 'test cds'
define view ztest_cds as select from sflight 
association [1..1] to spfli 
 on sflight.carrid = spfli.carrid
 and sflight.connid = spfli.connid{
key carrid,
key connid,
key fldate,
price,
currency
}
```

**ztex_cds** code:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewAppendName: 'ztextend_cds'
@EndUserText.label: 'test extend cds'
extend view ztest_cds
with ztex_cds 
association to sbook as _book
        on _book.carrid = sflight.carrid
        and _book.connid = sflight.connid
association [1..1] to scustom as _cust
on _cust.id = _book.customid{
_book.bookid,
_book.customid,
 _cust.id,
_cust.name,
_cust.form,
_cust.street
}
```

what should I to get `ztest_cds` active?

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: In ztex_cds, i association another table. When I active ztest_cds, I receive this error message:Table name _book unknown or shadowed by an alias.
what should I can active ztest_cds?